# data.table operations by column name with spaces fails

Tags: r, data.table

**Reproducible example**

```
#Use the Iris data set
library(data.table)
iris 
colnames(iris)[3] <- "Petal Length"
iris <- as.data.table(iris)
```

Accessing column without space is fine

```
iris[,Petal.Width]
```

however access a column where the name contains a space doesn't work

```
iris[,Petal Length]
iris[,'Petal Length']
```

The only solution seems to be

```
iris[,iris$'Petal Length']
```

**Comments**
I'm new to data.table. I understand there's a lot of quirks in data.table; is this one of them? I would change my variable names to get rid of spaces, but I'd prefer not to if i didn't need to. I also read a previous questions regarding just column names - and I understand in the two years since that last question updates have allowed it - this can be seen in the ease when the colname has no spaces.

Comment: i feel the need to add that sticking to names with spaces just seems stubborn. it will only prove a nuisance. three possible alternatives: `petal_length`, `petal.length` and `petalLength`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Update 2020-04-22

`data.table` has evolved and now `iris[ , 'Petal.Length']` will return a one-column table (i.e., character and integer literal vectors in `j` can be used for column selection). There have also been ample updates in extending `.SDcols` for common use cases to do column filtration (subsetting by pattern on name, subsetting by logical aggregation); see the NEWS for more details.

Leaving the below for posterity.

---

Just use `with = FALSE` as explained under [data.table FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) points 1.1-1.3 and 2.17:

```
iris[ ,'Petal Length', with = FALSE]
```

and make sure to read the excellent [introduction to data.table PDF vignette and the new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

---

In this case, for what you expect (a vector), using `[[` is more appropriate:

```
iris[['Petal Length']]
```

Alternatively, you can also refer to column names as if they were variables in `j`:

```
iris[, `Petal Length`] # note the backticks.
```

Comment: quite on the contrary, very happy about it, looks way cleaner now and is more informative! I wanted to edit the backticks in anyway and the [[ part is even new to me! so I learned something new

Comment: Thanks for that. Did not know a FAQ existed. Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure this works for subsetting too? If, say, you have a condition `iris[ ,'Petal Length' == <X>, with = FALSE]` this seems not to properly work anymore.