# Sum of columns with partial string match R

Tags: r, string, sum, data.table, match

I want to add two columns based on partial matches of their string value

```
a <- c("ChrM","ChrM","ChrM","ChrM","ChrM")
b <- c(5,6,7,10,11)
c <- c(0,0,3,0,1)
d <- c(2,1,0,1,0)

dfa <- data.table(a, b, c, d) 
colnames(dfa) <- c("ID","pos","cr H-MN-8A","cr H-MN-8B")
#I don't know how to make a column name with a string value (with " " and "_")
  ID     pos        cr H-MN-8A cr H-MN-8B
1 ChrM   5          0          2
2 ChrM   6          0          1
3 ChrM   7          3          0
4 ChrM  10          0          1
5 ChrM  11          1          0
```

I want to be able to add the last 2 columns "cr H-MN-8A","cr H-MN-8B" based on their partial string match "cr H-MN-8" and then write the result into a column while also comparing it to a value, so the return is true or false. 
I had something akin to

```
dfa <- lapply(dfa, function(x) x[, newval := as.numeric(col1+col2>=1)])
```

I have more than two string matches withing titles (they're all paired up on the same dataframe). Any ideas? Thanks!

(Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using `data.table`

Comment: I'll echo this sentiment "i feel the need to add that sticking to names with spaces just seems stubborn. it will only prove a nuisance. "  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757316/data-table-operations-by-column-name-with-spaces-fails

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: @mtoto TRUE or FALSE, expressed as 1 or 0 respectively

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune That's what I've got to work with :(

Comment: I just noticed it makes zero sense. It something more akin to `newval := as.numeric(col1+col2>=1)`

Comment: see answer, is this what you're looking for? with `>=1` the new values will be all `1`'s

Comment: @PierreLafortune i'm blushing teehee

Comment: haha it's the truth though. I would tell whoever created the names upstream and anyone expecting it downstream to rekonize son

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try the following `data.table` approach

```
dfa[,`H-MN-8` := as.numeric(rowSums(.SD) > 1), .SDcols = grep("cr H-MN-8", names(dfa))]

dfa
#     ID pos cr H-MN-8A cr H-MN-8B H-MN-8
#1: ChrM   5          0          2      1
#2: ChrM   6          0          1      0
#3: ChrM   7          3          0      1
#4: ChrM  10          0          1      0
#5: ChrM  11          1          0      0
```

Comment: pro-tip: writing `+(rowSums(.SD) > 1)` will do the conversion more concisely (if a bit more nebulously)

Comment: @MichaelChirico there's growing push back with SO r-taggers on that. Readability vs conciseness and all

Comment: @PierreLafortune I'm with you -- probably inadvisable to leave an answer rife with insider tricks, especially on a beginner's question. But also nice to pepper stuff like this _alongside_ the more limpid answers for the curious and intrepid ;-)

Comment: What if the string changes (I've got like 8 groups) and I want to transfer it (it's stored under names from a list) so I don't have to type a unique key for each one? As in I want to select everything before the A or B that vary between the groups and then do the operations on the groups whose only difference is A or B.

Comment: This is a new question, not in your original problem. Please post a new question if you have one, instead of cramming it into the comments.

Comment: Wilco. Thanks for the help!